# Angular 8 : Set title of group box from ts code

Tags: html, angular, title

I have a component that contains groupbox:

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Title</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Is it possible to set the title of the groupbox from the ts code ?

Comment: in .ts declare a parameter : title: string = 'my title value'; and in html <legend>{{title}}</legend>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your component file:

```js
@Component({
//...
})
export class MyComponent {
  title = 'My Title';
}
```

In your template:

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>{{ title }}</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Find more on [Angular Template Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)